# if __name__ == "__main__" syntax error

Tags: python, sql

```
 # insert values to db
    try:
            if sensor1error == 0:
                    sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO temperaturedata SET dateandti$
                    # This row below sets temperature as fahrenheit instead$
                    #sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO temperaturedata SET dateandt$
                    databaseHelper(sqlCommand,"Insert")
                    sys.exit(0)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

in the last line im having an error i dont know what's this. please help me..

Comment: you miss an `except` statement before entering a next block, and some quotes in the `sqlCommand`

Comment: Also, your string is on multiple lines...

Comment: Please, read [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to the code block. Which added the missing except block. And fixed the indentation error. So that should help. Otherwise you have to be clearer what kind of error you are getting.

```
try:
    if sensor1error == 0:
        sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO temperaturedata SET dateandti$"

        # This row below sets temperature as fahrenheit instead$
        #sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO temperaturedata SET dateandt$

        databaseHelper(sqlCommand,"Insert")
        sys.exit(0)
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Worth noting that OP should replace `Exception` with a specific Exception class more pertinent to their use case.

Comment: Yup, would agree.

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn Python syntax first, in case your brain was storming with ideas and can't find the problem below is the lists you can check.

1. `except` block is missing
2. There is a common error in Python `indentation error`, the code should be inside the if block.

The code modification can be similar as,

```
from __future__ import print_function  

try:
    if sensor1error == 0:
        sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO temperaturedata SET dateandti$"

        # This row below sets temperature as fahrenheit instead$
        #sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO temperaturedata SET dateandt$

        databaseHelper(sqlCommand,"Insert")
        sys.exit(0)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's one of a great many errors in this code. If you are going to answer, at least address them all.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I accidentally  pressed submit the answer first while i was editing for a proper explanation to question; before some senior moderators down voting question since whoever asked may not be a beginner may be a part from his work, he was confused spent long time to solve this; i know that feel :/

Answer (score 0):

Please use multiline string in your SQL query and dont use comments in between.

Also you need to catch the exception if you are putting a try block, add an `except` block to handle that exception

In the end give proper indent in `if` block.